# Hidden dropdown menu like Windows 8 right side menu

Tags: vb.net, python-3.3, powershell-4.0

I am not sure what I call it... The pulling menu in windows8? You know the one with the setting etc in it

See this picture:

http://www.eightforums.com/attachments/tutorials/3414d1330544186-lock-log-off-restart-shut-down-switch-user-windows-8-a-settings-1.jpg

How do I make one?

I can use vbscript..I know you can't use this to make what I want...

Vba and just over the last month powershell.

I was looking at Python... People keep telling me it's awesome to use can you make a menu bar like that picture in Python?

Suggestions to what to start learning and reading would be great?

Comment: I think making the menu wil be easy.but my question is in what kind of program you want to add it? Or is the menu the whole program?

Comment: Shortcuts for work.... Unlock, change passwords in AD and various other junk I use in vbscript and poweshell excel Vba.... Want to convert everything to another language and learnt the same time.... I know I can't just convert it it would be different etc etc